# Connecting to Venus GPS, checking received UART message, seems garbled

Tags: raspberry-pi, uart, gps

I'm trying to integrate to a Venus VENUS634FLPx GPS chip that I bought through SparkFun many years ago (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/9133). I'm connecting to it through UART and I'm getting NMEA messages however they come across seriously garbled. Here is one of the better ones:

```
b'$GPGGA,121\xbd.000,2400.0\xf87,N,12100.00\xc6V\x8d\x193\xcb\x980,0.0\xfc\xf7\x06\xc6\xd6\x8d\x193\x193\xcc\x96M,\xfd30*67'
```

Here is the datasheet format for this message:

```
$GPGGA,hhmmss.sss,ddmm.mmmm,a,dddmm.mmmm,a,x,xx,x.x,x.x,M,,,,xxxx*hh<CR><LF>
```

The hhmmss.sss is "121\xbd.000" and it looks like some bytes were eaten there. Ultimately what I want to do is check the checksum at the end which is supposedly an XOR of all characters in the message excluding the leading $, trailing *, and 2 character checksum.

I'm using a Raspberry Pi W with /dev/ttyS0 enabled and I have an external power supply powering the GPS chip at 3.3v. The ground from the power supply is linked to the Raspberry Pi as well. The baud rate I'm using is 9600.

My code is Python using the pyserial package v3.4.

Any recommendations on how I can debug this or what I could check would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Edit 1: `python -m serial.tools.miniterm`

```
    (venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/subcommander $ python -m  serial.tools.miniterm 

--- Available ports:
---  1: /dev/ttyAMA0         'ttyAMA0'
--- Enter port index or full name: /dev/ttyS0
--- Miniterm on /dev/ttyS0  9600,8,N,1 ---
--- Quit: Ctrl+] | Menu: Ctrl+T | Help: Ctrl+T followed by Ctrl+H ---
$G�␆����N��V�Y��,M���f�Y3�0.���␘��.0��␆F��04��␆����*��␆��␙3��[c��Y3f0���V�L�$G�␆␆��˧,�+c��f���0���Y3��0.���␘���00�␆F���4,������␙��0.��␙3f�K,n�Y3v�06��F�L���s␆��3���,E��3f��00��␚Y3�,0���LX��.0�␆␆F�̘5�␆������0����F��,K���Y3��0��Vv�$��␆F�͖O��cV��f̖�0���␚Y��,0���L��f␙�␆␆f��0��␆������00��3␙3,K��␚Y��,0��Vf�%�s␆��3���,E��3̖�00��␚Y��,0���L���.0␆␆F�̘���␆������00��3␙�,K��␚Y3�,0��V␖�$��␆��͖N�cV��f�,�00��4Y��,0���L��5.��␆␆f��0��␆␆������00��3␙3,K��␚Y��,0��V␆�%��␆��͖O�cV��3̖�00��␚Y3�,0���L���.��␆␆F�̘4�␆������00��3␙��,K��␚Y3�,0��V6�$�s␆��3���,E��3l��00��␚Y��,0���L��3␙�␆␆F�̘5�␆������0����F��,K���Y3��0��V&ַ���f͖�4�u�␙3��00��␖�Y��,��␆�L��8.��␆��f�0�00�␙��10��3f��00��␙3��,,N�␆␆���0.�␆ƶ��Ж���␆�fe���␖��04��F�V��00�␆␆���Ж�c�␆�f���1���␆F�00��␆␆���,N�␆␆��̘.��ƶ��h��8,��3e���3f��04��F�V.0��␆␆���A,��Ʀ�f���12��3̘�00��␙3��,,N�␆␆���0.�␆ƶ��Ж���F�fe���6���04��F�V�00�␆␆���Ж�,,��3���13��␆␆�00��␆␆���,N�␆␆��̘.��ƶ��h��8���3e���F����4��F�V�␙3̃␆f�Y4��,,�3f��14��␆␆��00��␆␆��,N�␆␆��̘/�0,k��h��̘,�␆Ʀ�81��f̘�0���˘
```

Answer: the grounds from the GPS and raspberry pi were not tied together.

Comment: To start by ruling out any issues in your custom code, begin with `python -m serial.tools.miniterm -h` and then run that to terminal as a test.  Double check your wiring.  Ideally examine the signals on a scope...

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I figured it out. it was the ground. i put it in the wrong pin. Thanks for miniterm though! I never knew about it.

Comment: Although  it seems like a minimal thing, please post the ground fix as an answer and "accept" it, otherwise the question will forever show as unresolved